# How do I 'listen' to text that is being entered in the textfield?

Tags: jquery

How do I get my script to listen to any text that is being typed within a text field?
I used the class '.ops'  and tagged it to various select fields and a text field. I'm only able to detect the changes in the select fields, but not able to detect the changes in the text field unless I press 'Enter'on the keyboard.

This is my current script (Inside the function contains an AJAX script).

```
$(document).on('change', '.ops', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple events here:

```
$(document).on('change keyup', '.ops', function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `input` event which occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface.

```
$('.ops').on('change input', function() {

});
```

example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMLyE/)